# Why is Vue stripping the style attribute in this one component

Tags: vue.js

I have one Vue component in which any style attribute on any tag in the component template is stripped from the rendered output. Vue 2.6. No build step. The component template is defined in a js template string. Style is stripped whether it's bound or static. Style attributes on neighbouring components are rendered just fine. There are [no carriage returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51239610/vue-is-removing-a-background-image-in-and-with-the-style-attribule) in my styles. Does this suggest anything to anyone ?

Here's the start of my component...

```
Vue.component("justif-choice", {
    template: `
<div style="top:500">
qsdfqdf
</div>
    `,
...
```

This is the line that calls my component...

```
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
          &lt;justif-choice ref="justifChoice" &gt;&lt;/justif-choice&gt;
```

And here's the rendered output...[image]

Comment: Can you give an example/error code?

Comment: No error. No warnings in the console. Code coming, I just can't figure out what to post !

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it. The style rule I was testing, top:500, needed 'px' to be valid. So it was the browser stripping it, not Vue? There may be more to this story because the same code works fine on another page, but adding 'px' has fixed it.